# Replace a Fragment with another from a separate java class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Recycler View in a Fragment that I have an adapter class for in a separate file. I am trying to make it so that when you click on a RecyclerView Item it replaces the current fragment with a new one. The code to replace a fragment with another that I had been using previously is this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, NewFragment.class, null);
        transaction.addToBackStack("CurrentFragment");

        transaction.commit();
```

And this works inside the fragment, but since I have to call it from the java class I tried this instead:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, NewFragment.class, null);
        transaction.addToBackStack("CurrentFragment");

        transaction.commit();
```

And this just layers the new fragment on top of the current one. If I try making a class in the Current Fragment with the transaction code in it and call it, it doesn't work because of the static context.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't be using fragment transactions at all if you are using a `NavHostFragment` as your code snippets imply. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a bottom navigation view and I want to replace the original fragment (in the bottom navigation view) with a different one, but with the bottom navigation still showing. Is this not the way to do that?

Comment: If you're using a `NavHostFragment`, you need to [navigate](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate).